# Reverse Proxy (ARR) and ScriptResource.axd Issue

Tags: iis-7, reverse-proxy, sitefinity, scriptresource.axd

I'm having issue when I run my website on the Reverse Proxy layer. It will display the following javascript error.

```
=> Message: 'Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager' is null or not an object

=> Message: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Sys._Application' cannot be converted to type 'Sys._Application'.
Parameter name: instance

=> Message: 'Telerik' is undefined
```

They are all pointing to the "ScriptResource.axd" file and default file (frontend and backend).

When I run the website on the application layer (direct access without using the proxy), there is no error as shown above.

Is there any configuration need to enable reverse proxy server(ARR) to work?

Using Sitefinity 3.6 and IIS7

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Under caching in the server farm, select "Include query string" in the query string support drop down list.